# iPhone: Application new version doesn't appear on AppStore Updates list!

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have been going through this strange issue and have no clue what's going on! I have my application in Appstore live. When I update an application, I increment the version counter(2.0 -> 2.1 for example) before resubmitting an app. I get message from Apple that my application is reviewed and live on AppStore but my application doesn't appear on AppStore updates list! Could anyone please get me to right direction. Is it something to do with Apple side or something wrong in my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out! I have already automatic updates feature added in my App which automatically gets the contents from my website when I add new content and increment the version so I don't need to resubmit the application. When application needs to be resubmitted I shouldn't update the version on my website else existing app was getting that version information automatically and my application wasn't getting listed in updates list!

I am not 100% sure if this was the case but now everything works fine! If I get chance to reproduce this behaviour in next app's update then I will confirm it and update here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did it passed a lot of time since you've got the message saying that your new version is ready for sale? Usually it takes a while until the application appears in the update list. Give it a little bit of time (a couple of hours) and if still doesn't appear try contacting Apple.

Comment: Actually it happened for two of our applications and they never listed on updates list so I am bit worried now.

Comment: Are you sure you've selected that the update is supposed to be release automatically? If not you have to connect to iTunes Connect and release your update to the public.

Answer (score 0):

App updates do not appear in the iTunes listing of New apps.

Use the iTunes search feature to see if your new update is available from the App store already.

There are 3rd party sites which list app updates, but some of them only update their listings once per day.